# Why does my function call not print out what it's supposed to?

Tags: python

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, blocking, b = None):
        self.blocking = blocking

    def printerthing(self):
        print "hi this is a test"        

a = A(True)
a.printerthing
print("5")
```

Comment: flgged it as "not a real question"

Comment: The title begs a snarky answer.

Comment: @Sanj, you don't flag it as not a real question, that's a reason to vote for closure. And, if all you're concerned with is the title, that's easily fixed :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not actually *calling* the function, you're just accessing a reference to it (and then doing nothing with it). You probably want:

```
a.printerthing()
```

Comment: Yes, a.printerthing returns a reference to the printerthing method (function) which is then discard by the interpreter since it's not being bound to a name (assigned to a variable).

The reset of the code is rather inscrutable as well (why are you creating a "blocking" attribute which you're not using and why does your __init__ declare a defaulted argument which is not used by its definition).

Comment: Good catch, bradley, I've been bitten by this occasionally. @Jim, I suspect OP has reduced the problem down to a small test case which exhibits the undesirable behaviour. That's actually a _good_ thing, not something to nitpick at :-) The number of undecipherable "what's wrong with my 6000-line code snippet?" questions we see are the bad thing, this is an absolute godsend compared to those.

Comment: That's exactly what I did; I took a snippet of a class and worked it down as much as possible to try to get at the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try `a.printerthing()`?

Each method call has to have a ()

Answer (score 0):

print in python3.x is different from print in python2.x

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

class A:
    def __init__(self, blocking, b = None):
        self.blocking = blocking

    def printerthing(self):
        print("hi this is a test")      

a = A(True)
a.printerthing
print("5")
```

it prints "5".

Andy

Comment: Andy, I think OP also wants it to print out `hi this is a test` as well.

Comment: i see. then a.printerthing() is the way to go!

Comment: well, if it's python 3, a.printerthing() still wouldn't print as expected, because it's written as a statement (ala 2.x) instead of a function.   This answer was a very good catch.